# POI doesn't copy ppt slide notes

Tags: apache-poi

When I tried to copy a ppt slide to a new ppt document. The slide presentation part was copied, but the slide notes was not copied.

I tried the [MergePresentations.java](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/MergePresentations.java) from POI example. It does not copy the notes either.

I explicitly get notes from the source slide, then set it to the target slide. It still didn't work.

```
XSLFNotes sreNotes = srcSlide.getNotes();

XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlide targetSlide = ppt.createSlide();
targetSlide.importContent(slide);
targetSlide.setNotes(sreNotes);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getNextFileName(RESULT_DIR, charName));
ppt.write(out);
out.close();
```

How to copy ppt slides with notes? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The method [XSLFSlide.setNotes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.html#setNotes-org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Notes-) is not implemented yet. It is only present to fulfill the requirements of interface [Slide](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/usermodel/Slide.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get notes from the source slide, then set it to a new slide. Of course, the text formatting will be lost.

```
//Get note from a slide
private static String getNotesText(XSLFSlide slide) {

    XSLFNotes mynotes = slide.getNotes();
    for (XSLFShape shape : mynotes) {
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
            XSLFTextShape txShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
            for (XSLFTextParagraph xslfParagraph : txShape.getTextParagraphs()) {

                resultBuffer.append(xslfParagraph.getText())
                .append("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return resultBuffer.toString();
}

private static void createNewPpt(XSLFSlide slide, Dimension pageSize) throws IOException {

    try (XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow()) {

        ppt.setPageSize(pageSize);

        XSLFSlide targetSlide = ppt.createSlide();
        targetSlide.importContent(slide);

        XSLFNotes targetNotes = ppt.getNotesSlide(targetSlide);
        for (XSLFTextShape targetShape : targetNotes.getPlaceholders()) {

            if (targetShape.getTextType() == Placeholder.BODY) {

                targetShape.setText(getNotesText(slide));
                break;
            }
        }


        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getNextFileName(RESULT_DIR, charName));
        ppt.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```